# fortran reshape function causing segfault

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, reshape

I recently moved a code I use routinely to a new machine. The code worked on the old machine just fine. On the new machine, I'm now using intel to compile instead of gnu.

Anyways, a line is giving me a segfault and I don't understand why. Looking for help from someone smarter than me. The line in question uses reshape:

```
allocate( tlev(ncol, nlay + 1) )
tlev = 0.0
tlev = reshape(thalf(:,:,:),(/ncol,nlay + 1/), order = (/1,2/))
! thalf has shape [x,y,nlay + 1], ncol = x * y (where x = 480, y = 241, nlay = 60)
```

The error message, specifically, is:

forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred

It's not clear to me why this is happening. I don't think I'm exceeding memory limits. If I comment out the reshape line, the code proceeds.

Comment: What compile-time options are you using? Which version of the compiler?

Comment: I'm using the following compiler: ifort (IFORT) 2021.2.0 20210228

And flags: 

-g -traceback -check all -check bounds -check uninit -ftrapuv -debug all -gen-interfaces -warn interfaces

No optimization.

Comment: Add also `-heap-arrays ` and next time please show more information. See alse [mcve].

Comment: See also https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/segfault-with-reshaping-and-transposing-big-arrays/m-p/746900